# How to define an upper limit for an std::ostringstream after which all appended data is discarded?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have some existing code that uses a `std::ostringstream` as an temporary buffer. To increase robustness, I want to define an upper limit for the buffer size (e.g., 16 KB). When the limit is exceeded, all following data that is append, should be silently discarded. Ideally, after logging a warning.

What is the simplest way of doing it? `std::ofstream` seems to have no efficient way of getting its current size. I can only think of `my_stream.str().size()`, which seems to be highly inefficient.

Of course, I can manually keep track of the number of inserted chars by keeping an extra counter, but maybe there is an elegant alternative that I am missing. I saw that `ofstringstream` has an internal buffer (`rdbuf()`) that can be replaced.

Is it possible (and practical) to use it to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to extend [stringbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringbuf/) into your own class and use that within `ofstringstream`. Then it should be trivial to implement your max limit. It looks like [`stringbuf::overflow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringbuf/overflow/) is the function you want to overload.

Alternatively you could wrap the `std::ostringstream` within another class which checks `size` before writing to it. How do you conclude that this is inefficient? As long as the size is not calculated every call, it is just the matter of navigating down the indirection.

Edit: Missed the word "copy" in the reference, but yes, once you wrap it, you could keep your own counter.

Alternatively, you could use [`tellp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/tellp/) to try and figure out how many characters are written, as long as it always points to the end.

> Return Value
>   An integral value of type streampos with the number of
>   characters between the beginning of the output sequence and the
>   current position.

Comment: Thanks, `stringbuf::overflow` looks interesting. How do I conclude that `my_stream.str().size()` is inefficient? According to the documentation, `str()` returns a copy of the internal string. I agree that wrapping it and keeping a separate counter avoids that problem.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I believe I have a efficient solution for size(), pls check my edit.